# To create a custom field

Tags: custom-field, fields

Is it possible to implement the following requirement in declarative way?

1. One custom field
2. Ability to enter URL of size greater than 500 characters and displays only first 50 characters.
3. Editable field

Is this possible using any field types already available in Salesforce? Is it possible to implement this in a declarative way?

I know that we can use URL field to enter URL of 255 characters and display first 50 characters. But is it possible to extend the length to 510 or more than that?

If yes how?

Comment: I first posted two custom fields as I needed the functionality for both the fields.

Comment: Fiest let us know what have you treid yet

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use  "Long Text Area" data type which length is 131,072  and you can enter a valid url .
Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can not use URL type field if character length is more than 250.

Alternative approach is by using two fields:

1. Create  Long Text area field to save the URL then,
2. Create a formula field of type text. Use hyperlink function and refer above created field in the formula.
3. You can provide a friendly name of the URL this way which can be less then 50 characters.

   HYPERLINK(url, friendly_name [, target])

[Hyperlink function](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tips_for_using_hyperlink_formula_fields.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't reference a Long Text Area in a formula field. You get the following

> Error: You referenced an unsupported field type called "Long Text Area" using the following field: ...

Because of this you can't leverage a formula and the HYPERLINK to store long urls.
Some URL shortening can help you achieve this.